# Type casting silently failed with dynamic proxy and java generics

Tags: java, generics, casting, dynamic-proxy

IMy question concerns the behavior of type casting with dynamic proxy and java generics. More specifically, I want to instrument a servelet object using dynamic proxy. For better reusability, I adopted some generic code template for creating proxy objects as below.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T instrument(final T aT) {
    T proxy = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(aT.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{MyServelet.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object aProxy, Method aMethod, Object[] aArgs) throws Throwable {
        ..... instrumentation logic goes here
        }
    });
     System.out.println("proxy class " + proxy.getClass());
     System.out.println("input class " + aT.getClass());
     return proxy;
}
```

Here T is my concrete servelet implementation class that implements MyServelet Interface. However, If I run the above method it prints out

```
proxy class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0
input class class MyServeletImplementation
```

So I wonder what happened to the type casting statement in the code snippet. It seems like it quietly failed since the proxy didn't get casted to MyServeletImplementation, but it didn't throw ClassCastException either. Can somebody shed me some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cast took place in the actual compiled bytecode of the method, because of [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens).

When generating bytecode, the compiler treats any variable of a parameter type as having the same type as that parameter type's upper bound, or `Object` if the type is unbounded.  So if `T` in your method had the constraint `<T extends MyServelet>`, the compiler would have treated `proxy` as a variable of type `MyServelet`, and inserted a cast.  However, as `T` is unbounded, it's treated as a variable of type `Object` - thus, no cast.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the dynamic proxy is that you don't care about the actual class of the proxy that is being returned.  You just care that it implements all desired and specified interfaces.

[The Javadocs for `newProxyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)) state:

> Returns:
>
> a proxy instance with the specified invocation handler of a proxy class that is defined by the specified class loader and that implements the specified interfaces

So, `newProxyInstance` returned an instance of `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0` (whatever that is, we don't really care), but it also made sure that it's a `MyServelet`.  You should be able to cast it to `MyServelet` without a `ClassCastException`, because `newProxyInstance` created the class to implement that interface, and you specified that it should by passing in `new Class[]{MyServelet.class}`.

For type casting not to have failed, Java generics must have inferred that `T` is `MyServelet`, not `MyServeletImplementation`.  Perhaps when you called `instrument`, you did so like this:

```
MyServelet proxy = YourClass.instrument(new MyServeletImplementation());
```

So the cast was to `MyServelet` which should succeed, and not to `MyServeletImplementation`, which should fail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you needed to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is because the compiler was trying to warn you that you were doing something wrong.  by adding the suppression, you told the compiler that you didn't care because you knew what you were doing.  maybe you shouldn't have added the annotation if you didn't uderstand why you were getting the warning in the first place?

Hint: the generic cast `T proxy = (T)` gets turned into `Object proxy = (Object)` by the compiler.  ("Type Erasure" as mentioned in another answer).